# Why I am getting "dynamic initialization is not supported for a __constant__ variable"?

Tags: cuda, constants, nvidia

I have  the following structs:

```
enum BoundSide { right, left, top, bottom, back, front };

template<typename T, size_t D>
using vec = array<T,D>;

//fpr short and static Vector Fields like c_i
template<typename T, size_t D, size_t Q>
using vec_set = vec<vec<T, D>, Q>;

template<typename T, size_t D>
struct VELOCITY_BOUND_DEV;

template<typename T>
struct VELOCITY_BOUND_DEV<T, 2>
{
  BoundSide side;
  int center{};
  int width{};
  T u_w;        //velocity
};


template<typename T, int D, int Q>
struct SimDomain_dev 
{
  vec_set<T, D, Q> c;       //discrete velocity-set
  vec<T, Q> w;          //discrete weights
  vec<grid_size_t, D> gridDim_L;

  VELOCITY_BOUND_DEV<T, D> bound;
}
```

I declared a `__constant__` variable like this:

```
template<typename T, int D, int Q>
__constant__ SimDomain_dev<T, D, Q> sd_dev;
```

and I copy the data form a temporal host variable to the device variable like this:

```
 cudaMemcpyToSymbol(sd_dev<T, D, SimDomain<T, D>::Q>, &sd_temp,0, sizeof(SimDomain_dev<T,D, SimDomain<T, D>::Q>))
```

The Class array in `vec` and `vec_set` is a container-class which works on the device side (that works).

So, why I'm getting the error "dynamic initialization is not supported for a `__constant__` variable"?

Comment: what are `vec_set` and `vec`? I would guess there is a constructor trying to run somewhere. You can't do that

Comment: Your edit doesn't answer the question. Do they have constructors?

Comment: These are alias for the class-type array. This container is a replacement for std.:array and works on the device too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int center{};
int width{};
```

Initialize `center` and `width`, also, depending on how `vec` and `vec_set` are defined, they may have constructors of their own.

Comment: `vec_set` and `vec` are constructs of the class `array`. This is a replacement for `std::array` and works on the device too.

Comment: As stated by @talonmies they cannot have constructors

Comment: Ok, I got the error because of the initialize of `center` and `width`. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

To use constant memory for such structs [which include dynamic initialization directly or indirectly], One general solution is:

Struct Definition:

```
struct STRUCT_WITH_DI {
....
};
```

Definition of `__constant__` in `.cu` as an array:

```
__constant__ char struct_data_arr[sizeof(STRUCT_WITH_DI)];
```

Convect `__constant__ array` to the struct:

```
__global__ void compute_kernel(){
    const STRUCT_WITH_DI* struct_data_ptr = reinterpret_cast<const STRUCT_WITH_DI*>(struct_data_arr);
    const STRUCT_WITH_DI &struct_data = *struct_data_ptr;
}
```

Copy struct data to the `__constant__` memory:

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbolAsync((const void*) &struct_data_arr,  (const void*) &struct_arg,
                                         sizeof(struct_arg), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, c_stream )
```